# Jar files in android

Tags: android, android-source, android-logcat

I am trying to enable logs in the android source code. The normal procedure is as follows -

1. Edit all the files in which you want to enable the logs = 15-20 minutes
2. Build the whole binary - 1 hour
3. Install the binaries on phone and boot up the device - around 15 minutes

Is there any way by which I can write a apk file which can enable the logs automatically directly inside the device upon its installation, i.e. skip the first 2 steps and save a lot of time.

For example in the file AudioManager.java, if a few lines of log is commented out, I need to uncomment it and then build the binaries again for an hour in order to receive proper logs.
Is there a shorter way to do this where I do not have to build the whole code again and can make some changes in the phone which will enable the requested logs.

Comment: Can u bit more clear?

Comment: Hello Sankar, I have added an example. Hope it clears it a bit. Please ask me for any further clarification.

Comment: is it possible to uncomment a java statement from binary? I don't think so. commented statements are not included in class files.